# Rock Paper Scissors Running Twice Error

Tags: python

I'm new to programming. I have written code for the rock paper scissors game but there is one bug that I can't seem to fix. When the game closes, the user is asked if he wants to play again. If the user answers yes the first time, then plays again then answers no the second time, the computer for some reason asks the user again if he wanted to play again. The user must enter no in this case. This is because although the user answers no, the answer gets reset to yes and goes over again. How can this be fixed?

```
# This code shall simulate a game of rock-paper-scissors. 
from random import randint
from time import sleep 

print "Welcome to the game of Rock, Paper, Scissors." 
sleep(1) 

def theGame():  
    playerNumber = 4 
    while playerNumber == 4: 
        computerPick = randint(0,2) 
        sleep(1) 
        playerChoice = raw_input("Pick Rock, Paper, or Scissors. Choose wisely.: ").lower()
        sleep(1) 

        if playerChoice == "rock": 
            playerNumber = 0  
        elif playerChoice == "paper":
            playerNumber = 1
        elif playerChoice == "scissors":
            playerNumber = 2    
        else:
            playerNumber = 4 
            sleep(1) 
            print "You cookoo for coco puffs." 

    print "You picked " + playerChoice + "!"
    sleep(1)  
    print "Computer is thinking..." 
    sleep(1)
    if computerPick == 0: 
        print "The Computer chooses rock!" 
    elif computerPick == 1: 
        print "The Computer chooses paper!" 
    else: 
        print "The Computer chooses scissors!" 
    sleep(1) 

    if playerNumber == computerPick:
        print "it's a tie!"
    else:
        if playerNumber < computerPick:
            if playerNumber == 0 and computerPick == 2:
                print "You win!" 
            else:   
                print "You lose!" 
        elif playerNumber > computerPick:
            if playerNumber == 2 and computerPick == 0: 
                print "You lose!" 
            else: 
                print "You win!"            
    replay()

def replay():
    sleep(1) 
    playAgain = "rerun" 
    while playAgain != "no": 
        playAgain = raw_input("Would you like to play again?: ").lower()
        if playAgain == "yes":
            sleep(1) 
            print "Alright then brotha." 
            sleep(1) 
            theGame()
        elif playAgain == "no":
            sleep(1) 
            print "Have a good day." 
            sleep(1)  
            print "Computer shutting down..." 
            sleep(1) 
        else: 
            sleep(1)  
            print "What you said was just not in the books man." 
            sleep(1)  

theGame()
```

Comment: `replay` calls `theGame`, and `theGame` calls `replay`. But also, `replay` calls `theGame` in a while loop. I don't think you need to do both of those. What happens if you delete that last `replay()` in `theGame`'s definition?

Comment: In that case, there would be no first call to replay so replay would not run.

Comment: Oh, right. Ok, in addition to that, you could call `replay()` instead of `theGame()` at the bottom of the program. Maybe add a theGame() call at the beginning of replay() so it doesn't ask you "do you want to play again?" before you play the first time. But then `replay` is doing more than just prompting for a replay, so maybe it makes sense to rename it... Perhaps `enter_game_loop` or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of the way the call stack is created.

The First time you play and enter `yes` to play again, you are creating another function call to `theGame()`. Once that function call is done, your program will continue with the `while` loop and ask if they want to play again regardless if they entered `no` because that input was for the second call to `theGame()`.

To fix it, add a `break` or set `playAgain` to `no` right after you call `theGame()` when they enter `yes`

```
while playAgain != "no": 
    playAgain = raw_input("Would you like to play again?: ").lower()
    if playAgain == "yes":
        sleep(1) 
        print "Alright then brotha." 
        sleep(1) 
        theGame()
        break ## or playAgain = "no"
```

Answer (score 1):

You should break out of the loop after calling `theGame`.  Imagine you decided to play again 15 times. Then there are 15 `replay` loops on the stack, waiting to ask you if you want to play again.  Since `playAgain` is `"yes"` in each of these loops, each is going to ask you again, since `playAgain` is not `"no"`